# How to set an Sql Server DB to Read-Only mode forever

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, database-security

I am providing a .bak file to someone who as per my business scenario, may only be allowed to view the db ,and not modify anything in the database and may not even be allowed to take a backup of the database.

Is this possible ?

[Note : I have the privillege of restoring the .bak file to their SERVER]

Comment: What do you mean? The scenario doesn't make much sense. You can't `restore the .bak file to their SSMS`, SSMS is the IDE, not the database. If you give them a `bak` file they can copy it wherever they want. Will you restore it to their server or to one of your own and give them access?

Comment: NO. If the database is attached to a sql server there is no way to prevent an admin user from making a backup. There is also no way to prevent an admin user from doing whatever they want to the database. Preventing this kind of thing would go against the concept of an admin user in the first place. If you don't want somebody to be able to do things to your database don't put it on their server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant in their server . Thanks Sean Lange

Comment: You must takeaway dbo privilegs from everyone (except yourself) and DENY ALL as well as remove write rights

Comment: @Sean Lange. Your comment looks like an answer. Why not make it an answer? I would upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is attached to a sql server there is no way to prevent an admin user from making a backup. There is also no way to prevent an admin user from doing whatever they want to the database. Preventing this kind of thing would go against the concept of an admin user in the first place. If you don't want somebody to be able to do things to your database don't put it on their server.